# Sort result set based on information in another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for pointers and possible t-sql examples. I have a list of products that I want sorted based on the number of units sold in another table.

So, I have a ProductID field in the Products table and a ProductID field in an OrderLine table and I want to do the following:

```
SELECT ProductID, etc, etc FROM Products WHERE clause here ORDER BY (UnitsSold in other table)
```

I expect my other query to be similar to this:

```
 SELECT ProductID, SUM(Qty) AS UnitsSold Order By UnitsSold
```

But I have to take in to account that a product may have never been sold before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a subquery (or CTE) for the calculation:

```
SELECT ProductID, etc, etc
FROM Products p left outer join
     (select ProductId, sum(qty) as UnitsSold
      from OrderLine ol
      group by ProductId
     ) ol
     on ol.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE clause here
ORDER BY coalesce(ol.UnitsSold, 0) desc;
```

The reason for doing the aggregation in the subquery is so you don't need to put all the fields in the `select` in the aggregation.  The `select` and `where` clauses don't need to change

The `left outer join` is to get values for all products, even those that haven't sold.

The `coalesce()` is to be sure that non-matching rows go last (or first) depending on whether you want most units first or least units first.

If you are ordering by `UnitsSold`, then you might want to include that value in the `select` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well use a left join on the "sales" table and a `coalesce` (you could also use `isnull` in sql server) operator on your sum

```
select p.productId, coalesce(sum(s.qty), 0) as unitsold
from Product p
left join sales s on p.productid = s.productId
group by p.productId
order by unitsold
```